# how to edit/change POST response?

Tags: java

I got a school assignment asking me to change the content of JSON Response

from
{"name" : "Bob"}

to
{"greeting" : "Hello, Bob"}

this is my ResponseDTO

```
public class HelloWorldResponseDTO {
    private String name;
}
```

and this is my Entity

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    public HelloWorldResponseDTO convertToResponse() {
        return new HelloWorldResponseDTO(this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a library that requires these `DTO` classes? This is a lot of boilerplate for what boils down to some simple data substitution and a JSON parser.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.